# Is it possible to to run a target build stage in docker without running all the previous build stages

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am newbie to docker and trying to explore multistage build. I want to run a specific stage on docker `docker build -t build-stage-tag --target build`

I expect it to run the following stages `dependencies --> compile --> build` and skip the `test`. But it so happens that it runs the test stage as well.

Let me know if my understanding of multistage build `--target` is wrong or there is some error in my docker file.

What I want to do is run the `build` stage without running the `test` and vice-versa.

This is how my Dockerfile looks :

```
# Pull base image
FROM openjdk:8u171 as dependencies

# Install Scala
## Piping curl directly in tar
// do some stuff

# Copy source into container
COPY . /usr/src/app

FROM dependencies as compile
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Test and build the jar in the same step to save time
RUN sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true compile
RUN sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true assembly

FROM compile as test
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dtest_db_user=root -Dtest_db_password=password -Dtest_db_host=localhost coverage test coverageReport

FROM compile as build

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /root

COPY --from=compile /usr/src/push/target/scala-2.12/app-assembly-?*.?*.?*.jar ./push.jar
COPY --from=compile /usr/src/push/config/jvm.config ./jvm.config
COPY --from=compile /usr/src/push/entrypoint.sh /bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["docker", "blah"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable to use buildkit like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t build-stage-tag --target build -<<EOF
FROM alpine as base
RUN echo "running BASE commands"

FROM base AS test
RUN echo "running TEST commands"

FROM base AS build
RUN echo "running BUILD commands"
EOF
```

output:

```
[+] Building 4.4s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                               0.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                            0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 204B                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                0.0s
 => [base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [base 2/2] RUN echo "running BASE commands"                                                                                                                 1.4s
 => [build 1/1] RUN echo "running BUILD commands"                                                                                                               1.5s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                          0.7s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                         0.6s
 => => writing image sha256:c6958c8bb64b1c6d5a975d8fa4b68c713ee5b374ba9a9fa00f8a0b9b5b314d5e                                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/build-stage-tag                                                                                                              0.0s
```

Comment: A reference for why this answer works
https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage

Answer (score 0):

It should be also possible via Docker `build` option [`--no-cache-filter`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/build/#no-cache-filter).

> Couple of examples to get a grasp:
>
> - `--no-cache-filter target1,target2` invalidates cache for both targets `target1` and `target2` (most common usecase) equivalent to
>   `--no-cache-filter target1 --no-cache-filter target2`
> - `--no-cache --no-cache-filter !target1,!target2` invalidates cache for all targets but `target1` and `target2` (less common usecase)
> - `--no-cache-filter mount:id1` invalidates cache for the cache `mount` with id `id1` (defined with RUN
>   `--mount=type=cache,id=id1,...`)
> - `--no-cache` would keep current behavior of disabling cache for all targets and cache mounts

[Source](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1213#issue-508658474)

---

## Example

```dockerfile
FROM debian:bookworm AS base

FROM base AS initial

RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        ca-certificates \
        curl && \
    apt-get autoremove --purge -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf '/var/lib/apt/lists/'* '/tmp/'* '/var/tmp/'* '/usr/share/doc/'*;

FROM initial AS build

RUN mktemp;

FROM build AS entry

CMD ls -- '/tmp';
```

---

```bash
$ alias 'run-test=docker run -it --rm -- test';
$ docker build -qt test -- . > '/dev/null' && run-test;
# tmp.inG87WVHGR
$ docker build -qt test -- . > '/dev/null' && run-test;
# tmp.inG87WVHGR
$ docker build --no-cache-filter 'build' -qt test -- . > '/dev/null' && run-test;
# tmp.r361seh761
$ docker build -qt test -- . > '/dev/null' && run-test;
# tmp.r361seh761
$ docker build --no-cache-filter 'build' -qt test -- . > '/dev/null' && run-test;
# tmp.zYXnte8xLA
```